# Am receiving the output of another object, which is wrong

Tags: java

My program has to create two dog objects and give them attributes. In the Dog class, I have to have one constructor with fleas, and one w/o. When I use the program, I receive the information from the wrong object in one of my outputs.

```
public class JavaProgram{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Dog dog1 = new Dog ("Luca", "mutt", 'M', 22, 5 );
        Dog dog2 = new Dog ("test", "Golden Retriever", 'F', 12, 9, true );

        System.out.println("Dog1's name is " + dog1.getName() + ", its breed is " +
        dog1.getBreed() + ", its sex is " + dog1.getSex() + ", its age in months is " + 
        dog1.getAge() + ", its weight in pounds is  " + dog1.getWeight());

        System.out.println("When Dog1 eats it makes the noise " + dog1.getEating() +
        ", and when its barks the noise made is " + dog1.getBarking());

        System.out.println("Dog2's name is " + dog1.getName() + ", its breed is " +
        dog2.getBreed() + ", its sex is " + dog2.getSex() + ", its age in months is " + 
        dog2.getAge() + ", its weight in pounds is  " + dog2.getWeight());

        System.out.println("When Dog2 eats it makes the noise " + dog2.getEating() +
        ", and when its barks the noise made is " + dog2.getBarking() + "It does" + dog2.getFleas());
    }
}
```

```
public class Dog{

    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private char sex;
    //In months
    private int age;
    //In pounds
    private double weight;
    private boolean fleas;
    private String yesFleas;
    private String noFleas;
    private String eating;
    private String barking;


    public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight){
        this("Chomp, chomp, chomp", "Woof, woof, woof");
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public Dog(String name, String breed, char sex, int age, double weight, boolean fleas){
        this( "Chomp, chomp, chomp", "Woof, woof, woof", "have fleas, scratch, scratch, scratch", "not have fleas, yay!");
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.fleas = fleas;
    }

    public Dog(String eating, String barking){
        this.eating = eating;
        this.barking = barking;
    }

    public Dog(String eating, String barking, String yesFleas, String noFleas){
        this.eating = eating;
        this.barking = barking;
        this.yesFleas = yesFleas;
        this.noFleas = noFleas;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getBreed(){
        return breed;
    }

    public char getSex(){
        return sex;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public double getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }


    public String getEating(){
        return eating;
    }

    public String getBarking(){
        return barking;
    }
    public String getFleas(){

        if (fleas == true)
            return yesFleas;
        else
            return noFleas;

    }
}
```

I should get "Dog2's name is test, its breed is Golden Retriever, its sex is F, its age in months is 12, its weight in pounds is  9.0", but I get Dog2's name is Luca, its breed is Golden Retriever, its sex is F, its age in months is 12, its weight in pounds is  9.0

Comment: `System.out.println("Dog2's name is " + dog1.getName()` - typo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're printing dog1's name instead of dog2:

```
System.out.println("Dog2's name is " + dog1.getName()...
                                       ^^^
```

Comment: Surely it would be more appropriate to vote to close as a typo than to answer? (I can't see how this will be useful to other readers...)

Comment: @JonSkeet good idea, will do